# Mysql workbench reverse engineering

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench for a project connected to xampp. Whenever I try to modify the existing database by reverse engineering, making changes like adding new columns and some indexes to existing columns, I lose the changes / modifications in forward engineering.

Comment: Hi, can you add abit more detail to you question? I am guessing you have existing database and you reverse engineering that to scripts then modifying that and forward engineering that back into a new database? What changes are you making?  Also if you creating new scripts you will need a new database, if want to update your old database you going to have alter it.

Comment: Yes I was trying to update my existing database by reverse engineering it, I tried adding new columns and some indexes to existing columns but my database didn't update after forward engineering, also I have my mysql workbench connected to xampp i don't if that's causing the problem

Comment: did you run validation to see if there were any errors? if you live database has data in it there may be some constraints.